# QGraphicsScene image pos pixmap

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt Graphics Framework for displaying an image. I have opened a raw image in subclassed `QGraphicsScene` in `QGraphicsView` using `addPixmap()`. I have added zoom feature by using scale function and drag mode is set as scroll hand drag. Now, I need to get the pixel coordinates within the scene on mouse hover such that the x and y value show the pixel in the image (drawn by pixmap) the mouse is currently pointing to. I tried using `pos()` but it didn't work.

Here is the code from `Widget.cpp`:

```
img = openImage(dirPath2.toLocal8Bit().data(),
                sizeX,sizeY,file_heade,scan_heade,bpp,sign);
QPixmap x = QPixmap(sizeX,sizeY);
x.convertFromImage(img,Qt::AutoColor);
scene->addPixmap(x);
ui->disp_img->setDragMode(QGraphicsView::ScrollHandDrag);
```

`GraphicsScene.h`:

```
class GraphicsScene : public QGraphicsScene {
public:
    GraphicsScene(QWidget *parent) : QGraphicsScene(parent){}
};
```

(preferably the pixmap coordinates but even that doesn't happen and if the values change when zoomed I will use scale factor to get the original values)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start by reading about [Qt's Graphics Coordinate System](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/graphicsview.html#the-graphics-view-coordinate-system).

There are various layers of coordinate systems and you need to think about those with which you dealing with. At the top layer is the screen (or view), which is where the mouse coordinates reside.

The next layer from the view is the graphics scene. Graphics items, such as the QGraphicsPixmapItem which you added with addPixmap, reside here. The graphics scene can be visualised as a world of items, each with there own position and orientation.

Moving to the last coordinate system is an item's local coordinate system. If, for example, we take a rectangle, it may have local coordinates of (-5, -5, 10, 10) for (x, y, w, h). This item is then placed in the scene at some position. If its position is the origin of the scene (0,0), then the item's local coordinates would read the same as its scene coordinates.

However, if we move the rectangle +5 units in x-axis, its local coordinates are the same, but its scene coordinates would now be (0, -5, 10, 10).

Likewise, the view (QGraphicsScene) is a window into the scene and can be looking at the whole scene, or just part of it. As the view's top left coordinate is (0,0), it may map onto (0,0) of the scene, or may not, depending on what area of the scene the view is looking at.

So, by getting a mouse position you're starting in the view's coordinates and need to convert to the scene's coordinate system. Fortunately, Qt provides lots of useful functions for this at every level.

To convert the mouse coordinates from the view to the scene, you can use the view's [mapToScene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html#mapToScene-5) function.

Using the scene coordinates you can then get an item and map that to the local coordinate's of the item with the item's [mapFromScene](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#mapFromScene).